# Baby Sharks in Hungry Shark?

Tags: hungry-shark

What are the purpose of baby sharks in Hungry Shark for the kindle Fire? Do they have any bonuses that are useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.facebook.com/HungrySharkEvolution/posts/603301673016343) Baby Sharks will help you out a bit.  Also, you can eventually unlock a second baby shark, which would help out even more.

> The baby sharks don't get hurt and they eat fish people but nothing much bigger than them. Baby GW cannot eat hammerheads or evil GW but he can bite them to hold em still for you